# Pycharm IPython tab completion not working (within python console)

Tags: python, ipython, pycharm, tab-completion

So I have searched high and low for an answer regarding this and I am starting to come to the conclusion that it simply isn't a feature for Pycharm.

I am using IPython in Pycharm and I cannot get tab completion to work at all.  If I start IPython in the terminal within Pycharm, there is no issue and tab completion works as promised.

What am I missing here?  I am using Pycharm Community 4.5.4.

Thanks!

Comment: One thing i have noticed is that I can Ctrl + Space and get completion... Still expecting there to be tab completion though?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I emailed PyCharm support and asked the same question. Their response is that tab completion isn't currently supported, but you can vote [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-9345) to move it up their priority list.

After years of tab completion in my muscle memory, Ctrl + space is not an ideal alternative.